# Passing a parameter to a custom find method in cakephp 3.x

Tags: php, cakephp-3.0

I want to build a custom find function that retrieves bands for a given genre, i have tried this but the function can't access to the parameter `$genre`:

```
public function findGenre(Query $query, array $options)
{

    $genre = $options['genre'];
    $bands = $this->find()->contain([
        'Genres' => function($q){
            return $q->where(['Genres.id' => $genre]);
        } 
    ]);
    return $bands;
}
```

I can access the `$genre` outside the  `contain()` method, but not inside it.
My question is, how can i pass the `$genre` var to the `function($q)` inside the contain method.

Comment: What error is your code giving you? Are you aware that your code should conventionally be $bands = $query->contain([...]);, so it can be applied to an existing query?

Comment: the query works fine when i'm not using a condition, but when i add the condition with the param, it can't access the param `$genre`, i added an edit to the post

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found where the problem is, i had to use the keyword `use` after the `function($q)`, so that part of the code will look like this

```
$bands = $this->Bands->find()->contain('Genres', function($q) use ($genre){
    return $q->where(['Genres.name'=>$genre]);
});
```

Also,the `contain()` method returns all the data even if the bands don't belong to a genre, but when i replaced it with `matching()` it worked just fine.

I hope this will help anyone who is having a similar problem in the future.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing same issue but now it's resolved. I will explain you step by step:
    My tables are:
    articles: `id`,`name`,`status`,`created`
    tags:`id`,`name`,`status`,`created`
    articles_tags: `id`,`article_id`, `tag_id`

my query is this:

> I want to pass my `$tag_data['slug']` in matching variable but
>   directly this variable is not working in query. So I put in simple
>   `$uses` variable and now it's working properly.

```
$uses = $tag_data['slug'];
$contain_article = ['Tags'];
$query = $this->Articles->find('All')
    ->where(['Articles.status' => '1'])
    ->contain($contain_article)
    ->matching('Tags', function ($q) use ($uses) {
        return $q->where(['Tags.slug' => $uses]);
    });
```

Please try this :-)